# The first homology and Betti number

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've read the following in a book:

> On the projective plane we have $b_1=0$ which suggests that every
>   cycle of edges may be the boundary of a chain of faces. This is,
>   however, not true; taking the sphere with antipodal points identified
>   as our model, consider the path which runs halfway around the equator.
>   This is a cycle and lies in the kernel of $\partial_1$, but is not in
>   the image of $\partial_2$.

My understanding is that the first Betti number $b_1$ is defined as the dimension of $H_1=\ker \partial_1/\text{im } \partial_2$. Here
$$\partial_k\colon C_k(T)\to C_{k+1}(T)$$
for a chosen triangulation $T$ of $RP^2$. So if $b_1=0$, then $H_1=\{0\}$ and hence $\ker \partial_1=\text{im } \partial_2$; that is "every cycle of edges may be the boundary of a chain of faces." So I'm not sure what is it that I'm missing. So $b_1=0$ does not imply $H_1=\{0\}$?! Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: $H_1(P^1(\Bbb R))\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is a nonzero *torsion* group.

Comment: Betti numbers measure rank.  Are you familiar with rank-torsion description of finitely generated abelian groups?

Comment: @EricTowers The book merely gives the definition of rank and torsion. What is confusing me is that "the first $\mathbb{R}$-homology group of $RP^2$ is trivial". If this is true why we can't say that "every cycle of edges may be the boundary of a chain of faces"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a comment to the question:
Beware: $\mathbb{R}$-homology (and $\mathbb{Q}$-homology) make torsion vanish.  However, $\mathbb{Z}$-homology keeps the torsion mentioned by Lord Shark the Unknown in his comment.  So in $\mathbb{R}$-homology, $b_i = 0$ does imply $H_1(\cdot ; \mathbb{R}) \cong \{0\}$.

Here's where the difference comes in: take a chain of edges that "goes around the boundary of a chain of faces twice".  (Note that this is slightly fanciful language -- these chains are just $\mathbb{Z}$-weighted sums of edges.)  Call this edge chain $c$ and the face chain $b$.  So we have 
$$  2 \partial b = c  \text{.}  $$
In integral homology, we're stuck, there is no integer we can mulitply through to clear the coefficient of $\partial b$.  In $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, we can multiply through by $\frac{1}{2}$ and discover that 
$$  \partial b = \frac{1}{2}c  \text{.}  $$

This literally happens in $\mathbb{R}P^2$ -- there is a $2$-chain whose boundary is not homologous to zero, but two copies of it is.  (In homotopy, there is a loop that is not nulhomotopic, but for which two copies *is* nulhomotopic.  This is where I got my fanciful language above.)  It turns out this chain generates $H_1$, so $H_1$ is surjected by $k \partial b$ as $k$ ranges over the integers.  But every even $k$ is nulhomologous, so $H_1$ only contains $0$ and $\partial b$ and their table of sums is the same as that of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  So we find $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

However, in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ coefficients, we *have* $\frac{1}{2}$ to simplify the relation and so $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \partial b = 0$ also.  This kills all of $H_1$, so $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Q}) \cong H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{R}) \cong \{0\}$.

Comment: This clarifies a lot, Eric. Would it be correct to say that the author is not careful when he says "This is a cycle and lies in the kernel of ∂1, but is not in the image of ∂2" ? My impression is that to specify the validity of this statement we **must** determine whether were are talking about integer coefficients or real coefficients for our chains. Thanks!

Comment: The author's claim "this is a cycle and lies in the kernel ..." is *correct* -- it is a union of closed loops, so is in the kernel of $\partial_1$, but is not in the image of $\partial_2$, otherwise a *single* copy of the $1$-chain would be nulhomotopic (because $\partial_1 \circ \partial_2$ annihilates everything).  It takes two copies of the $1$-chain to land in the image of $\partial_2$, and *that* is the thing that is sent to zero, leaving $0$ and $\partial b$.

Comment: I can see what causes the difference between R and Z homologies, thanks to your answer. But I still don't understand how "This is a cycle and lies in the kernel of ∂1, but is not in the image of ∂2" can be a true statement in the **R**-homology case. My reasoning is as follows: $H_1(RP^2)=\ker\partial_1/\text{im }\partial_2=\{0\}$, implies $\ker\partial_1=\text{im } \partial_2$. So any member of kernel of $\partial_1$ is in the image of $\partial_2$. What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: What 2-chain has boundary that runs halfway around the equator?  If restrict attention (briefly) to one hemisphere bounded by the equator, any such 2-chain has a boundary component halfway along the equator and another that crosses the hemisphere between these two endpoints.  Its antipodal doppelganger in the other hemisphere covers the other half of the hemisphere and the antipodal image of the other path component -- you get two loops one on the equator and one elsewhere.  There is no 2-chain whose boundary is only one copy of the equator.  This is literally what he says.